# how to get for xml raw with value in between open and close tags tsql

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I require output as -

```
<g> 
<text x="480" y="846">Dakshin Bastar Dantewada</text>
<text x="460" y="833">Bijapur</text>
<text x="475" y="809">Narayanpur</text>
<text x="475" y="792">Uttar Bastar Kanker</text>
<text x="466" y="765">Rajnandgaon</text>
</g>
```

Using for xml raw, i am getting output as -

```
<g> 
<text x="480" y="846" DistrictName = "Dakshin Bastar Dantewada" />
<text x="460" y="833" DistrictName = "Bijapur" />
<text x="475" y="809" DistrictName = "Narayanpur" />
<text x="475" y="792" DistrictName = "Uttar Bastar Kanker" />
<text x="466" y="765" DistrictName = "Rajnandgaon" />
</g>
```

The code i am trying on is :-

```
SELECT     
               ( SELECT
                      X AS x ,
                      Y AS y ,
                      DISTRICTNAME
                      FROM
                      dbo.MYDISTRICT d1
                      WHERE
                      d1.STATEID = @pStateId
                 FOR
                    XML RAW('text') ,
                    TYPE
                 )
FROM      dbo.MYSTATE
WHERE     dbo.MYSTATE.STATEID = @pStateId AND           dbo.MYSTATE.COUNTRYID = @pCountryId

FOR
XML RAW('g'), TYPE
```

I require district name in between text xml raw opening and closing tags.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `RAW` you get either attributes **or** elements. Use `FOR XML PATH` if you want to specify your structure in detail:

```
SELECT     
               ( 
               SELECT
                      X AS [text/@x],
                      Y AS [text/@y] ,
                      DISTRICTNAME AS [text]
                      FROM
                      dbo.MYDISTRICT d1
                      WHERE
                      d1.STATEID = @pStateId
                 FOR
                    XML PATH(''),
                    TYPE
                 )
FROM      dbo.MYSTATE
WHERE     dbo.MYSTATE.STATEID = @pStateId AND           dbo.MYSTATE.COUNTRYID = @pCountryId

FOR
XML RAW('g')
```